# Is $v-v_\circ=\beta\ln\left(\frac{\beta+v}{\beta+v_\circ}\right)$ solvable for $v$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-functions

In the equation

$$v-v_\circ=\beta\ln\left(\frac{\beta+v}{\beta+v_\circ}\right)$$

where $v_\circ\,, \beta \gt0$ and $v \in (-\beta , v_\circ]$

Turns out that we are unable to represent $v$ as a combination of elementary functions of $\beta$ and $v_\circ$.

And the Lambert's W function is helpful here.

Then, how can we solve the above equation?

Comment: the answer couldn't be represented by any elementary functions. it could be represented by 'Lambert W function' which is a transcendental function.

Comment: @WongAustin how then?

Comment: @AHB Try looking up the mentioned function.

Comment: @Lovsovs ok. let me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$v-v_\circ=\beta\ln\left(\frac{\beta+v}{\beta+v_\circ}\right)$$
$$e^{v-v_\circ}=e^\beta\left(\frac{\beta+v}{\beta+v_\circ}\right)$$
$$(\beta+v_\circ)e^ve^{-\beta-v_\circ}=\beta+v$$
$$-(\beta+v_\circ)e^{-2\beta-v_\circ}=(-\beta-v)e^{-\beta-v}$$
$$-\beta-v=W_k(-(\beta+v_\circ)e^{-2\beta-v_\circ})$$
$$v=-\beta -W_k(-(\beta+v_\circ)e^{-2\beta-v_\circ})$$
Where $W_k$ is the lambert W function.

Comment: The OP asked for an **analytical** solution.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Doesn't appear so anymore.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. That's bad, because it totally changes the intent of the question.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Its not so bad if the question is changed within relatively short time.  Though yes, changing the question is quite confusing.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Yes, you are right. sorry. But if I kept it like that, it would be a junk question and this answer would also be irrelevant, because the answer would simply be "no". Or maybe with a little more explanation. But now, This more looks like a useful question for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Wong Austin's answer, the multi-valued nature of complex exponentiation gives the Lambert W multiple branches. However, one root is obvious. The equation can be rearranged as $f(v)=f(v_\circ)$ with $f:=v-\beta \ln(\beta+v)$. Thus $v=v_\circ$ works.

Comment: Yes, that is the trivial solution. In fact this was a physics problem which asked what will be the return velocity of a projectile thrown upward (with air drag).